# How do I load a screen in Android that has an image?

Tags: android

I am trying to navigate from my Intro screen to a second screen when the user clicks on `graphic_a`. For some reason the application quits when I click on `graphic_a`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I have following code in `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the View that shows the graphic_a
        ImageView graphic_a = findViewById(R.id.graphic_a);

        // Set a click listener on that View
        graphic_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // The code in this method will be executed when graphic_a is clicked on.
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Create a new intent to open the {@link SongAActivity}
                Intent songAIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SongAActivity.class);

                // Start the new activity
                startActivity(songAIntent);
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

So the user clicks on graphic_a, and they should be sent to SongAActivity.class, which has this code:

```
public class SongAActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.song_layout);


        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.graphic_x);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sgtpepper));
    }
}
```

And there is an xml file that goes with it:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/tan_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.musicplayer.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/graphic_x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

My logcat is:

```
04-18 23:01:36.568 27625-27625/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-18 23:01:36.641 27625-27638/? E/zygote64: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
04-18 23:01:36.642 27625-27638/? I/zygote64: Debugger is no longer active
04-18 23:01:36.757 27625-27625/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-18 23:01:37.141 27625-27652/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
04-18 23:01:48.710 27625-27652/com.example.android.musicplayer I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 2941438, I916dfac403
    Build Date                       : 10/03/17
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.21.02.00
    Local Branch                     : O18A
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
04-18 23:01:48.716 27625-27652/com.example.android.musicplayer I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
04-18 23:01:48.720 27625-27652/com.example.android.musicplayer I/zygote64: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
04-18 23:01:48.720 27625-27652/com.example.android.musicplayer I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-18 23:01:48.721 27625-27652/com.example.android.musicplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
04-18 23:01:53.009 27625-27625/com.example.android.musicplayer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-18 23:01:53.016 27625-27625/com.example.android.musicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.musicplayer, PID: 27625
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.android.musicplayer/com.example.android.musicplayer.SongAActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
        at com.example.android.musicplayer.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: can you please share what error is displayed in the console?

Comment: "Music Player keeps stopping"

Comment: @davidtspf, please provide a full logcat and your Android Manifest.xml also

Comment: I should have mentioned that the xml file is called "song_layout.xml".

Comment: You are making 2 activity for only showing two image, why don't you use setvisibility or setting image to one imageview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, in MainActivity.java file, you should change:

```
// Find the View that shows the graphic_a
ImageView graphic_a = findViewById(R.id.graphic_a);
```

**To**

```
// Find the View that shows the graphic_a
ImageView graphic_a = findViewById(R.id.graphic_x);
```

Or simply change image id in xml file from ***graphic_x*** to ***graphic_a***.

**Update 2:** From you log cat, you do not declare SongAActivity in manifest file yet. To fix this issue add below code to manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.android.musicplayer.SongAActivity"/>
```

Then try again.